# How to reroute traffic form one IP to another while keeping the IP?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, iptables

I currently have the following `iptables` rules in order to redirect traffic from `b.b.b.b` to `a.a.a.a`:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25566 -j DNAT --to-destination a.a.a.a:25566
-A POSTROUTING -d a.a.a.a/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25566 -j SNAT --to-source b.b.b.b
```

However, all traffic routed to `a.a.a.a` (from `b.b.b.b`) shows the IP address `b.b.b.b` as IP of incoming traffic.

How do we keep the original IP somewhere in the packet so the original IP will be shown to the other server we route the traffic to?

Comment: Keep the original IP by *routing* the packet rather than *forwarding with NAT*.  Typically one uses NAT because of insufficient IP address space to route.

Comment: @user4556274 Could you shed any light on how to do this?

Comment: It varies depending on platform.  On a typical linux, you would enable routing by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` to uncomment the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, then apply with `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`.  Packets coming in on one interface will then exit on the other if that is what the routing table calls for (`ip -4 route`).  However, if you have only one routable IP address (typical home setup), this won't work for internet traffic, although you can experiment with local routing within your home network.

Comment: Your second rule is rewriting the source IP (Source NAT). Have you tried it without?